# Blazor best practice to Initialize object

Tags: blazor

Given a Razor Component to display an object details, what is the best pratice to get that object from DB?

I my case I always set the object using OnInitializedAsync like follows:

> ```
>     private ProductModel productModel;        >               
>
>     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
>     {
>         productModel = await _productsService.GetObjectDetails(Id);                
>     }
> ```

I wonder if Im doing the best way in terms of performance or is there a better way, for example using OnParametersSet...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the `OnInitialized{Async}` method pair are called before the `OnParametersSet{Async}` method pair. The main difference between these pairs is that the first is called only once, when the component is created and initialized.

`OnParametersSet{Async}` method pair, however, is called:

After the component is initialized in `OnInitialized` or `OnInitializedAsync`. And at each subsequent re-rendering of the parent component, when a primitive parameter has changed, as for instance, ID (which is defined as a component parameter property), and if you also have complex-typed parameters defined in your component.

What you do is correct. But if you do that in `OnParametersSet{Async}` method pair, it would make no difference whatsoever...It would incur no overhead.

The good pattern is to use `OnInitialized{Async}` method pair, and if say, you want to call the same method (`_productsService.GetObjectDetails`) you call from OnInitialized{Async}, with a changed parameter value, you may call it from `OnParametersSet{Async} method pair`, depending on your general design.

Are you confused because of the `SetParametersAsync` method ? This is something entirely different than the `OnParametersSet{Async} method pair`, though related.

> I understud that OnParametersSet is mainly to use when parent component is passing parameters, SetParametersAsync I dont know any about it..

The `SetParametersAsync` method is not really considered a life cycle method. `SetParametersAsync` is executed before the `OnInitialized{Async}` method pair. You can inspect [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1395fa8574a574ca969463952d4c5e89e9febe89/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L211) to see what is going on... The role of the `SetParametersAsync` method is to set parameters supplied by the component's parent in the render tree or from route parameters. You may override it if you need, but usually you won't, depending on what you do.

Comment: I understud that OnParametersSet is mainly to use when parent component is passing parameters, SetParametersAsync I dont know any about it..

Comment: Thank you for your answear

Comment: Actually `OnInitialized{Async}` are called not once but *twice* if you set the rendering mode to `ServerPrerendered` so you should take that into account

Answer (score 2):

> in terms of performance

There will be very little diference. Don't bother. Your current code is fine.

> for example using OnParametersSet...

If that `Id` is a parameter that can change then OnParametersSet is the only *correct* place.